# File Explorer "forgetting" contents of PATH variable after several hours

Tags: windows-explorer, environment-variables, path

I ran into problems hitting the maximum length of the Windows *PATH* variable.  I read an article that suggested extending it by creating another environment variable, say *PATH1*, adding additional directory paths to that new variable, then adding `%PATH1%` to the *PATH* variable.  This works fine: I can see the directories in *PATH1* listed when I do `echo %PATH%` and applications relying on directories listed in *PATH1* seem to work okay.

However, after a few hours Windows File Explorer seems to forget the directories added to the *PATH1* variable.  I know it works right after a restart because *PATH1* includes a directory with shortcuts which I run frequently via the Run dialog.  Those shortcuts work for a few hours after a restart.  But eventually I'll try to run a shortcut from the Run dialog and get the message `Windows cannot find '<shortcut name>'`.  After that none of the shortcuts will work again until I restart the machine.

When I get that `Windows cannot find '<shortcut name>'` error message I can open a command prompt and run `echo %PATH%`.  It will still include the directories added to the *PATH1* variable.  So it's not like Windows as a whole has forgotten the directories in *PATH1*.  It seems to be just File Explorer.

Is there some memory pressure or something that might cause this after a few hours?  Is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Comment: What happens if you just [Restart Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/198815/use-this-secret-trick-to-close-and-restart-explorer.exe-in-windows/)?

Comment: Good question, I hadn't thought of that.  I'll try it next time.

Comment: You are trying to fight the wrong fight.  Trim down your path.  Just because every stupid company tries to put their crap in your path doesn't mean you NEED those things in your path.  Most of the tools that do this are Linux based.  On Linux, everything ends up in a pre-determined path that already exists (like /bin or /usr/bin).  On windows, they say F**k it! and add their product to the path.  If you are working on something like go or python, create a batch file to launch your environment and put the garbage there.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: The worst offender I've come across is SQL Server or, at least, its client tools, such as SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and SQL Server Integration Services.  I've found I need several versions of SSMS installed to allow me to edit SQL Server Reporting Services reports for different versions of SQL Server.  They just fill up the path.

Comment: Fair enough @SimonTewsi !  SQL Server is a bad actor in this case.. but usually when I see all of their crap in the path, it isn't on a machine with a go, python, java, whatever developer (where the paths get simply stupid).  Good point though.  I delete the SQL Server stuff from my path every time and oddly, it still works with no issues.

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas.  I'll try taking the SQL Server directories out of the path and see if the keyboard shortcuts to the tools still work (eg "ssms" for SQL Server Management Studio).

Comment: @harrymc: Happened again and restarting Explorer worked.  If you'd like to submit an answer about restarting Explorer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this happening are unknown, perhaps some installed add-on
to Explorer or an interference by some installed program.
This perhaps can be checked by booting in Safe mode (if the problem
can happen in this mode).

A workaround that returns Explorer to its initial state is to
[Restart Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/198815/use-this-secret-trick-to-close-and-restart-explorer.exe-in-windows/).
The simplest method is to run Task Manager, Processes tab,
find Windows Explorer, right-click it and select Restart.
More methods can be found in the link.